# Whitelabel page error using sts and lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am using sts4.21.0
lombok version 1.18.30
java 21.0.1.0

i am trying to learn spring from youtube when I tried running these programs on my pc i got error after clicking on Add Product button although the when I manually type the address of product.jsp and successProduct.jsp i am able to view the entries and the entries are also updated in product table as well
This is the link of yt video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Iffr7JqSfE&t=2506s

this is the error

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jan 01 18:44:32 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

when we click on Add Product button the next page should show successProduct.jsp page but instead i am getting error

i tried using java 8 version by configuring environment variables but when i create the the spring starter project the option of using java version 8 wont show up i tried using the solutions on internet which tell to go to window --> preferences--> then adjusting installed jre and compliance level

```
successProduct.jsp
<h3>Product Added Sucessfully</h3>
<a href="product.jsp">Add New Product</a>
```

```
product.jsp
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addProduct" method="post">
    Product Id<input type="text" name="pid"/><br>
    Product Name<input type="text" name="pname"/><br>
    Product Price<input type="text" name="price"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product"/>
</form>
```

```
application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java16
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

```
ProductService.java
package com.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void addProduct(Product prod) {
        String SQL = "insert into Product values(?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, new Object[]{prod.getPid(), prod.getPname(), prod.getPrice()});
    }
}
```

```
ProductController.java

package com.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/addProduct")
    public ModelAndView addProduct(@RequestParam("pid") int pid, @RequestParam("pname") String pname, @RequestParam("price") int price) {
        
        Product prod = new Product();
    prod.setPid(pid);
    prod.setPname(pname);
    prod.setPrice(price);

        
    productService.addProduct(prod);//invoke /Model/Service/Action class

        return new ModelAndView("successProduct.jsp");//invoke view
    }
}
```

```
Product.java
package com.spring.boot;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString

public class Product {
    private int pid;
    private String pname;
    private int price;
}
```